# WCF un-expected end of file error

Tags: asp.net, wcf, c#-4.0

Recently I have upgraded my project `from .NET Framework 3.5 to 4.0.` For WCF I am using custom basic authentication.

Before conversion, all was working fine. However, after conversion I am getting "`Unexpected end of file error`". The stack strace is as below :

```
at System.Xml.EncodingStreamWrapper.ProcessBuffer(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, Encoding encoding)
   at System.Xml.XmlUTF8TextReader.SetInput(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, Encoding encoding, XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas quotas, OnXmlDictionaryReaderClose onClose)
   at System.Xml.XmlDictionaryReader.CreateTextReader(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, Encoding encoding, XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas quotas, OnXmlDictionaryReaderClose onClose)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.TextMessageEncoderFactory.TextMessageEncoder.WriteMessage(Message message, Int32 maxMessageSize, BufferManager bufferManager, Int32 messageOffset)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.WebMessageEncoderFactory.WebMessageEncoder.WriteMessage(Message message, Int32 maxMessageSize, BufferManager bufferManager, Int32 messageOffset)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpOutput.SerializeBufferedMessage(Message message)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpOutput.Send(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpPipeline.EmptyHttpPipeline.SendReplyCore(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpPipeline.EmptyHttpPipeline.SendReply(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpRequestContext.OnReply(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpContext.OnReply(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestContextBase.Reply(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestContextBase.Reply(Message message)
   at ihv1Role.auth.BasicAuthenticationInterceptor.ProcessRequest(RequestContext& requestContext) in d:\src\auth\BasicAuthenticationInterceptor.cs:line 78
```

The class and method in which I am getting error are as below :

p

```
ublic class BasicAuthenticationInterceptor : RequestInterceptor
{
    MembershipProvider provider;
    string realm;

    public BasicAuthenticationInterceptor(MembershipProvider provider, string realm)
        : base(false)
    {
        this.provider = provider;
        this.realm = realm;
    }
    protected string Realm
    {
        get { return realm; }
    }
    protected MembershipProvider Provider
    {
        get { return provider; }
    }

    public override void ProcessRequest(ref RequestContext requestContext)
    {
        HttpRequestMessageProperty request = (HttpRequestMessageProperty)requestContext.RequestMessage.Properties[HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name];
        string[] credentials = ExtractCredentials(requestContext.RequestMessage);

        if (credentials.Length > 0 && AuthenticateUser(credentials[0], credentials[1], IsTestMode))
        {
            InitializeSecurityContext(requestContext.RequestMessage, credentials[0]);
        }
        else
        {
            Message reply = Message.CreateMessage(MessageVersion.None, null);
            HttpResponseMessageProperty responseProperty = new HttpResponseMessageProperty() { StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized };
            responseProperty.Headers.Add("WWW-Authenticate",
            String.Format("Basic realm=\"{0}\"", Realm));
            reply.Properties[HttpResponseMessageProperty.Name] = responseProperty;
            requestContext.Reply(reply); // **Here I am getting error**
            requestContext = null;
        }
    }
}
```

If the username and password in header are valid then whole service runs well. I am getting this error only if request is not authenticated.

Any solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved it my self :

I had added  tag twice in Web.config.

Removed it and now my service is working fine.